# Is potting 1 ball in a turn a break in snooker?

Tags: rules, snooker

I am confused about what counts as a break in snooker. The [official rules](https://www.wpbsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/official-rules-of-the-game.pdf) have the following paragraph:

> 8. Break
>      A break is a number of pots in successive strokes made in any one turn by a player during a frame.

As I read it, it seems to me that potting 1 ball during a turn is counted as a break ("a number of pots" - 1 or more). However, commentators from my country are saying that a break is consisting of sequence of potted balls which implies (at least in my language) that at least 2 balls must be potted to say that the player made a break.

Is potting 1 ball enough for the break or it needs more than 1 ball?

Answer (score 2):

The definiton of *break* in the WPBSA rules is odd and has no meaning in practice. The World Snooker Tour definitely counts consecutive points rather than the number of pots.

The following image is from the China Open 2018:

[image: ronnie 147]

The Oxford Dictionary and Wikipedia define *break* correctly.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/break):

> *Billiards Snooker* 
>  A consecutive series of successful shots, scoring a specified number of points. 
>  ‘a break of 83 put him in
>   front for the first time’

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_snooker#Gameplay):

> A break is the number of points scored by a player in one single visit
>   to the table.

Snooker referees count the breaks loudly. Those breaks are officially recorded and most of the tournaments award the player who scored the highest break. Also note that foul points are not included in the breaks.

If we return to the main question, the answer is YES. Even one ball is a break, but indeed it is a one-point break. Let's say R. O'Sullivan potted a red ball in one turn. If he misses the next pot, the referee will say *"Ronnie O'Sullivan, one"*. *One* is the break here.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, I see two aspects. One is that the number of pots does not reflect the size of break, instead the number of points achieved via potting does.

The second aspect: Can number 1 be the size of a break in snooker? Answer: Yes, it can.

The definition of a break in snooker is clear enough. A break can consist of any number of point-giving balls consecutively potted by a player. If the definition says "a sequence of balls", well in this case potting only one ball is also a sequence, meaning that all other figures of the sequence are zeros. In maths, zero is also a number. Historically there have been cultures and customs where zero was not considered a number, but this was a long time ago...

So, yes, WPBSA rules are odd, but Oxford Dictionary and Wikipedia are correct.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer.